# animating views half working

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I am using the following code to animate a view on to another view. it works but only the navigation bar items are being animated the rest of the view just appears. I have tested on iphone and iphone simulator same problem on both. I would like the whole view to curl in not just the buttons.

```
loginView = [[loginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"login" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];        

    UIView *containerView = self.view;

    [UIView transitionWithView:containerView
                      duration:2.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                    animations:^{ [containerView addSubview:loginView.view]; }
                    completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: Please show more code. How are you setting up your navigation controller?

Comment: There is no code on the login view controller "loginController" it is being loaded from a XIB file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You speed up the animation duration which is default 3.0 so that it act like that

Comment: Please use proper spelling, not abbreviations. (For example "you", not "u".)

Comment: I got it working actually, I recreated the login view from scratch and now it works fine, not quite sure what the problem was.